# Nvidia GPU hang problem v12.10

Tags: 12.10, nvidia

I have a K43S Asus. Intel core i3 and a NVIDIA graphics card 610M.2GB
Ubuntu apport keep telling me my gpu hangs. And I think I have a resolution problem Is there anyway I could prove my resolution problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could open »NVidia X Server Settings« and see if you can change your resolution there to something higher or lower (if you have a resolution problem). You can open it from the dash.

Comment: :( what about the apport?